# What is the meaning of hello?

Tags: meaning, greetings

Maybe you think this is a bad question but:

My native language is Persian, in Persian when we see each other we say **salam** that is like **hello** in English. The actual meaning of  **salam** is  **peace** and **peace be upon you**, I know there is same meaning in Arabic, they say **السلام عليكم**, that means **peace be upon you**.

What is the meaning of **hello** in English, is that something like *peace*?

Comment: "Hello" is simply and literally "greetings"; it doesn't have any other overtones or connotations. You can confirm this and get more detail by [consulting any reputable dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/?w=Hello&ls=a) (which, for future reference, you should do *before* asking your next question about the meaning of a word).

Comment: @DanBron What does "greetings" mean?

Comment: @Araucaria It means *hello*.

Comment: @DanBron What does "it means hello" mean?

Comment: @Araucaria It means *it means hello*.

Comment: @DanBron What does *it means "it means hello"* mean?

Comment: @Araucaria it means *it means "it means hello"*

Comment: @Kermani: English greetings don't seem to have any literal meaning in use today. They are just derived from onomatopoeic shout-outs, as oerkelens' answer shows. I understand your confusion, since in many Asian languages this is not the case. In Hindi (Sanskrit), `namaste` means "I bow to you".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=holla&allowed_in_frame=0) it's just "a shout to attract attention", *possibly* related to an original meaning of "stop!":

> **hello**
>   1883, alteration of hallo, itself an alteration of holla, hollo, a shout to attract attention, which seems to go back to at least c. 1400. Perhaps from holla! "stop, cease." OED cites Old High German hala, hola, emphatic imperative of halon, holon "to fetch," "used especially in hailing a ferryman." Fowler lists halloo, hallo, halloa, halloo, hello, hillo, hilloa, holla, holler, hollo, holloa, hollow, hullo, and writes, "The multiplicity of forms is bewildering ...." Popularity as a greeting coincides with use of the telephone, where it won out over Alexander Graham Bell's suggestion, ahoy. Central telephone exchange operators were known as hello-girls (1889).
>
> Hello, formerly an Americanism, is now nearly as common as hullo in Britain (Say who you are; do not just say 'hello' is the warning given in our telephone directories) and the Englishman cannot be expected to give up the right to say hello if he likes it better than his native hullo. [H.W. Fowler, "A Dictionary of Modern English Usage," 1926]

Comment: Have you ever seen it written 'hullo' in Britain? I certainly haven't. Though I can remember seeing 'hallo' in the 1950s.

Comment: @WS2: I've _heard_ it for sure. P.G. Wodehouse supposedly used it in 1960 in _Jeeves in the offing_. [Here's](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/16377.How_Right_You_Are_Jeeves) an excerpt (down the page): We went into our routine.
‘Mr Wooster!’
‘Oh, hullo.’

Comment: But that is just fiction-writer's licence - simply an attempt to reproduce what Mr Wooster sounded like, isn't it? Just think, if we took our spelling cues from Mark Twain!

Comment: @WS2: ah, but doesn't spelling get decided by pronunciation, not the other way around? So if Mr Wooster _sounded_ like that, it only makes sense to spell it that way. Anyway, outside fiction, I quoted [Fowler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Dictionary_of_Modern_English_Usage) in my answer already. That dictionary has the spelling _hullo_, in Britain ;)

Comment: Interesting, I'd always assumed "hello" was descended from "hail". No connection?